# How to observe store values in a React Component?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a store, let's name it - 'myStore'

myStore.jsx

```
@observer
class myStore {
@observable public varToObserve;
...... rest of the logic
}
```

I have another wrapper of the above store, let's call it - myStoreWrapper.js

```
class myStoreWrapper {
myStore = globalStore.get('myStore');
} export default new myStoreWrapper();
```

I do not have direct access to myStore but only to myStoreWrapper and I want to observe varToObserve variable. what is the correct way to do so ?

Method A:

```
@observer
class myClass {

logic() {
    return myStoreWrapper.myStore.varToObserve;
}
render(){
    <myComponent myProp={this.logic()}
}
}
```

Method B:

```
@observer
class myClass {
@observable varToObserve = myStoreWrapper.myStore.varToObserve;

@computed
logic() {
    return this.varToObserve;
}
render(){
    <myComponent myProp={this.logic()}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's basically identical. You don't need to make separate `@observable varToObserve` thing and reassign it, because `myStore.varToObserve` is already an observable, just use it directly in the method:

```
// Depends on what you want to do inside of `logic` method.
// You can make it `computed` if you want to cache the output, derive some info from your observable and etc
@computed
logic() {
    // whatever logic you have
    return myStoreWrapper.myStore.varToObserve;
}
```